# Shrink Header Image on Scroll

Tags: css, javascript, theme-customizer

I am currently using the free version of neve on a local server and I am trying to make my sticky header responsive based on the scroll.

The text is responding correctly and becoming smaller, however the logo is not shrinking.
Outside of the javascript function, I can make it resize by changing the class in developer options but not responsive to the scroll.

Any help is appreciated!

---

Additional CSS

```
.header.shrink {
  font-size: 13px;
  position: fixed; 
    z-index:999999;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.site-logo.shrink img{
    max-height: 45px;
}
```

functions.php

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) { 
            $('header').addClass('shrink');
        $('site-logo').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('header').removeClass('shrink');
        $('site-logo').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Style.css

```
.site-logo {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.site-logo amp-img img {
  max-height: 60px;
}

.site-logo .brand {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.site-logo .title-with-logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.site-logo .title-with-logo > img:first-child, .site-logo .title-with-logo > div:first-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.site-logo h1, .site-logo p {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.site-logo small {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}


.site-logo a {
  color: #404248;
  display: inline;
}

.site-logo a:hover {
  color: #404248;
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a max-height set on .site-logo without the .shrink class?

Comment: In the "customize" view, the max-width is set to 75px as default (https://imgur.com/a/G35etXj)

Comment: So is it declared inline then or in a CSS class?

Comment: Honestly Im not sure, I posted a picture above

Comment: I also added the references to .site-logo from my style sheet above

Comment: You want to make sure you have this: `.site-logo img{max-height: 75px;}` and then when you add the class you get `.site-logo.shrink img{max-height: 45px;}`.  For transitions to work they have to go from value X to value Y.  Sometimes I forget and end up scratching my head for 20-30 minutes wondering why it's not working and then realizing I just forgot to specify the starting value. If you have a link you can share I can take a look at the actual rendered page.

Comment: I added that into the css and no luck. When Im looking at the elements dashboard in chrome, the .header.shrink function is triggered, but the .site-logo.shrink function isn't being triggered

Comment: Oh man... ...so `header` is an HTML tag.  You also seem to have it as a class though `.header` in your CSS.  But in your jQuery you target `$( 'header' )` which is looking for the HTML element.  Then you target `$( 'site-logo' )` but that's not an HTML element, that's a class.  So if you change it to `$( '.site-logo' )` it should start working.  So simple, I'm sorry I missed that detail.  You have to include the period (.) or jQuery/javascript doesn't know what it's looking for.

Comment: I posted the full set of changes and suggestions in an answer below.  Really sorry that I missed that initial detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's two things we need to look out for here.  We have to first make sure we specify to jQuery/javascript what it is that we're selecting.  In this code you are targeting the HTML header element and then also targeting 'site-logo' but jQuery can't find an element named 'site-logo'.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) { 
            $('header').addClass('shrink');
        $('site-logo').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('header').removeClass('shrink');
        $('site-logo').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The solution requires you to specify what it is you're targeting and since 'site-logo' is a class, you have to preface it with a period, like so:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) { 
            $('.header').addClass('shrink');
            $('.site-logo').addClass('shrink');
        }
        else{
            $('.header').removeClass('shrink');
            $('.site-logo').removeClass('shrink');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

As some pages may have multiple `<header>` elements, I'd strongly suggest that you also either target a specific class or ID for your main header unless you want them all to have the 'shrink' class applied when scrolling.

The other thing and I'm not sure if this was an issue or not, is that when you're using CSS transitions, you have to go from value X to value Y.  So if your `.shrink` class is setting `max-height:45px`, you should make sure the other class specifies a starting point for the same rule, like `max-height:75px`.

```
.site-logo img {
  max-height: 75px;
  -webkit-transition:max-height 1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition:max-height 1s ease-out;
  -o-transition:max-height 1s ease-out;
  transition:max-height 1s ease-out;
}
.site-logo.shrink img {
  max-height: 45px;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much :)

Comment: Fantastic to hear.  Remember to accept the answer if it does properly address your question.